# Forecasting Value in time series data with multiple independent variables

Tags: machine-learning, statistics, time-series, regression, forecasting

I have a data set attributes are (**Date, Value, Variable-1, Variable-2, Variable-3, Variable-4, Variable-5**), I have 100k plus rows.  *I wanted to predict the "Value" in the future based on 5 variables trained in time series manners, there will be seasonal trends and low and high scores in "Value"*. **Can someone suggest to me some statistical or machine learning/deep learning solution for this?**

[Here is Dataset Screenshot, I wanted to forecast Value Variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXHhF.png)

Comment: Please sort the date in the date column. It seems the time steps are different (IF so, you should consider it). Then, it is important to first plot your time series to see how it behaves. If you can find some sort of patterns among your variables/target, you might get some insight from MatrixProfile tool recently invented by Dr. Keogh. Its python package is available as well. Furthermore, I recommend you to take a look at tslearn pakcage as it can probably give you some tools to dig into your data and do data exploration prior to jumping to the main task. If spikes matter, LSTM  might help

Answer (score 0):

This is very interesting problem and you can use "Vector auto regression (VAR)" method to solve this problem. Packages are available in both R and Python to solve this problem.